# Authentication Cookie stops working when restarting server despite using ITicketStore and IDistributedCache

Tags: c#, docker, heroku, cookies, .net-core

My end goal is to be able to restart my dyno at Heroku and when the application has started again all users that where already logged in is still logged in. I have run a migration against the database to set up a table that `IDistributedCache` is using and then I have implemented `ITicketStore` that is using `IDistributedCache`. This works when I try it out locally: if I comment out `opt.SessionStore` I have to sign in every time I restart the application but with it I don't have to. However, when I sign in on my Heroku app I will have to sign in again after a restart. I get this warning that I don't know if it has something to do with it:

```
2017-10-03T13:45:09.144170+00:00 app[web.1]: [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
2017-10-03T13:45:09.144192+00:00 app[web.1]:       No XML encryptor configured. Key {bb36a43c-d5ed-4d03-9381-0e91868cd7a0} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
```

I have some logging so when I sign in I can see stuff like this in the log:

```
2017-10-03T13:44:48.848325+00:00 app[web.1]: Retriving Oskar Klintrot with key be94b055-4493-4602-9e72-2bcb6f009de2
```

However, after the restart nothing shows up in the log. Could the cookie be considered invalid or something and that the application isn't even trying to retrieve the user som the session store anymore? And is it even necessary to use `ITicketStore`, isn't the user normally stored in the cookie (The docs says `This is most commonly used to mitigate issues with serializing large identities into cookies.`)?

---

Specifications:

- dotnet core 2.0
- Docker running on hobby dyno on Heroku

---

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment CurrentEnvironment;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        CurrentEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        #region Dependency Injection
        services.AddTransient<ITicketStore, DistributedCacheTicketStore>();
        #endregion

        #region Database
        var sqlConnectionString = Configuration["CONNECTION_STRING"];

        services.AddDbContext<IntranetApiContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString));
        #endregion

        #region Migrate Database
        var dbContext = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IntranetApiContext>();

        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
        #endregion

        #region Options
        services.Configure<DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TimeoutMinutes = 60 * 24 * 30;
        });
        #endregion

        #region Distributed Cache
        services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = sqlConnectionString;
            options.SchemaName = "dbo";
            options.TableName = "DistributedCache";
        });
        #endregion

        #region Session
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });
        #endregion

        #region Authentication
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(opt =>
        {
            opt.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
            opt.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None, // TODO: Change when SSL enforcement is implemented, right now both http and https works
            };
            opt.SessionStore = services
                .BuildServiceProvider()
                .GetService<ITicketStore>();
        });
        #endregion

        #region Mvc
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            // Add authentication everywhere
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        #endregion
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        #region Session
        app.UseSession();
        #endregion

        #region Cookie Authentication
        app.UseAuthentication();
        #endregion

        #region Logging
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        #endregion

        #region Mvc
        app.UseMvc();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**DistributedCacheTicketStore.cs**

```
public class DistributedCacheTicketStore : ITicketStore
{
    private readonly DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions _options;
    private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

    public DistributedCacheTicketStore(
        IOptions<DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions> options,
        IDistributedCache distributedCache,
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
        _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        _dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(GetType().FullName);
    }

    public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
        return key;
    }

    public async Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Saving {ticket.Principal.Identity.Name} with key {key}");
        var ticketBytes = _dataProtector.Protect(TicketSerializer.Default.Serialize(ticket));
        await _distributedCache.SetAsync(key, ticketBytes, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions { AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_options.TimeoutMinutes) });
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
    {
        var ticketBytes = await _distributedCache.GetAsync(key);
        var ticket = TicketSerializer.Default.Deserialize(_dataProtector.Unprotect(ticketBytes));
        Console.WriteLine($"Retriving {ticket.Principal.Identity.Name} with key {key}");
        return ticket;
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Will try to remove key {key}");
        var ticketBytes = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key);
        if (ticketBytes.IsNotNull())
        {
            await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);
            Console.WriteLine($"Key {key} removed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key {key} missing");
        }
    }
}
```

**DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions.cs**

```
public class DistributedCacheTicketStoreOptions
{
    public double TimeoutMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

**AuthenticationController.cs**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var claimsPrinciple = await _userService.GetUserAsync(username, password);

            if (claimsPrinciple == null)
            {
                ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
                ModelState.AddModelError("Login", "Username or password is incorrect.");
                return View();
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                claimsPrinciple,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
                }
            );

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

**Migration_DistributedCache.cs**

```
public partial class Migration_DistributedCache : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DistributedCache] (
                                   [Id]                         NVARCHAR (449)     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL,
                                   [Value]                      VARBINARY (MAX)    NOT NULL,
                                   [ExpiresAtTime]              DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NOT NULL,
                                   [SlidingExpirationInSeconds] BIGINT             NULL,
                                   [AbsoluteExpiration]         DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
                                   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                               );


                               GO
                               CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_ExpiresAtTime]
                                   ON [dbo].[DistributedCache]([ExpiresAtTime] ASC);");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "Index_ExpiresAtTime",
            table: "DistributedCache");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "DistributedCache");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `machineKey` applicable in the application's config?

Comment: I haven't set `machineKey` anywhere so I guess not. Could that be the issue?

Comment: If it's used in .NET Core (I admittedly know very little about it). For non-Core applications it comes into play with the auth cookie when the application is running on a VM as the default key is hardware based. To get around this, you can specify in the application's config so that it always uses the same key.

Comment: Looks like [`DataProtection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/) is an equivalent to `machineKey`. I tried to use `Narochno.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DistributedCache` to store the keys in the `DistributedCache` but it didn't help.